# What browsers should we test while developing a Teams app?

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-teams

We are developing an app for Microsoft Teams, which is a web application that resides inside a teams shell. So, while testing the app in development mode, we have to use teams web app (teams.microsoft.com) and test the functionality on a dev tenant.

Major question here is **What's the browser engine that's running inside the Microsoft Teams Native app?**
In order to have the expectations for testing team right - What browsers should they be testing our web app with?

Currently we are testing on Chrome, Firefox and Microsoft Edge - **Should we support Edge Legacy and Edge on Chromium? or testing on Edge Chromium should be good?**

Answer (score 2):

The desktop full client runs on the [Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)) shell, which is using Chromium under the hood, so basically Chrome and "Edge Chromium" are much the same. However, as you've stated, the user could be using Teams in the browser. As a result, Firefox for sure is possible, but so are MacOS browsers and (gasp) even Classic IE!

That's aside from Mobile of course - if your app includes a Tab, then the mobile app might well load it inside the native mobile browser, making that a test vector too

Comment: Cool, that's pretty extensive coverage and I like the mobile-web suggestion too. Is there a timeline on when the Edge legacy would be sun-setting leaving the Edge chromium as the only choice?

Comment: It's not really a "Microsoft" (or "vendor") issue - it depends what the customer chooses to use. As an example, my team delivered a new intranet to a customer 2 months ago and had reports of it's being "slow" - it turns out large parts of the company were still (c2020!) using IE, so we finally helped them move to "Chromium Edge"